# Creating sitemap/nested list with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

Ive got a long list of xml elements.

Each element got an ID and a PARENT_ID.

How can I make a sitemap/nested list based on this? The elements with null value is the top parent elements.

I want to show the list with UL and LI`s in HTML.

```
<ROOT>
<SITEMAP>
    <ARRAY>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <NAME>Test</NAME>
        <PARENT_ID>NULL</PARENT_ID>
    </ARRAY>
    <ARRAY>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <NAME>Test2</NAME>
        <PARENT_ID>3</PARENT_ID>
    </ARRAY>
    <ARRAY>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <NAME>Test3</NAME>
        <PARENT_ID>NULL</PARENT_ID>
    </ARRAY>
    <ARRAY>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <NAME>Test4</NAME>
        <PARENT_ID>1</PARENT_ID>
    </ARRAY>
    <ARRAY>
        <ID>5</ID>
        <NAME>Test5</NAME>
        <PARENT_ID>4</PARENT_ID>
    </ARRAY>
</SITEMAP>
```

Comment: This is already a nested list in Xml format. What exactly do you want to do? And what do you mean by *elements with null value*?

Comment: Ah, sry.. Lacking some info.. I want a HTML list with UL and LIs where all the child are under their parents..

Comment: Ok, I see. Now that the general task is clear, could you please describe how far you've come/at what point you're stuck? i.e., while writing your XSLT code, what exactly poses an obstacle?

Comment: I have tried to solve the task with some templates, but I cant seem to get the logic right.. So, I think I can say that I'm stuck at the beginning..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key template will look something like this:

```
<xsl:template matches="ARRAY"> 
   <xsl:variable name="id" select="ID"/>
   <output>
      <!-- output goes here -->
      ...
      <!-- now process every ARRAY with a PARENT_ID equal to the current node's id. (I.e. its children.) -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/ROOT/SITEMAP/ARRAY[PARENT_ID = $id]"/>
   </output>
</xsl:template>
```

And you kick it off with:

```
<xsl:template matches="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/ROOT/SITEMAP/ARRAY[PARENT_ID = 'NULL']"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Be aware though that if there are any cycles in your hierarchy, this transformation will run infinitely.